# Inline Styling not working with ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, actionmailer, slim-lang

I am using SLIM and SASS for templates and styling emails in my Rails app.

The email looks fine when I view emails in browser with app environment set to development but in production environment the mail view comes out differently with inaccurate styles. Inline style tags were missing from images and headers in the email sent from production but appeared fine while in development.

What could be the reasons that might be causing the varying email styling in rails app production and development environment ?

PS: I am NOT using any gem for inline css.